# Is data context for main region available inside a contentFor block?

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

#### Background

I am trying to make a breadcrumb trail as per [this Evented Mind video (7:07)](https://eventedmind.com/classes/using-iron-router/layouts-and-regions).

#### The Problem:

I want the article title to show up next to a `/` divider.  Here's a pic for reference:

[image]

When I navigate to an article page, the `/` divider dynamically shows up in the breadcrumb trail, but the title does not show.

#### The Question

What's weird is that the title shows up in the main region, just below.  Shouldn't the data context for the template be available in the `contentFor` block?

---

#### The Code

Here is my layout template.  See the yield regions at the bottom:

```
<template name='Layout'>
    <div class="container">
        <div id="new-article">
            {{#linkTo route="blog.new"}}
                New Article
            {{/linkTo}}
        </div>
    </div>

    <ul class="breadcrumb">
        {{> yield "breadcrumbs"}}
    </ul>
    <div class="content">
        {{> yield}}
    </div>
</template>
```

And here is the template with the problematic breadcrumb trail (at the very top):

```
<template name='Article'>

    {{#contentFor "breadcrumbs"}}
        <li>
        {{#linkTo route="home"}}
            Home
        {{/linkTo}}
        </li>
        <li>
            <span class="divider">/</span>
        </li>
        <li>
            {{title}}
        </li>
    {{/contentFor}}
    
    <h1>
        {{title}}
    </h1>

    <div>
        {{author}}
    </div>
    <p>
        {{body}}
    </p>
    
    
</template>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem was not with the HTML at all.  It had to do with the data option set on the router.  For some reason **that I don't entirely understand and would love to have explained to me**, defining the data option on the "layout" function makes the data available to both the layout and to the template being rendered.

My hypothesis is that the two yield regions--breadcrumb and main--have different scopes that inherit from the layout.  Even though the code for the content for block gets written in the Article Template.

**Before:**
In the code below, the data option is getting defined on the article template.

```
Router.route("/blog/:_id", function(){
  this.layout("Layout");  

  this.render('Article', {
    data: function() {
      return  Articles.findOne({_id: this.params._id});  
    }
  });
}, {
  name: 'article.show'
});
```

**After:** In the code below, the data option is getting defined on the layout.

```
Router.route("/blog/:_id", function(){
  this.layout("Layout", {
    data: function() {
      return  Articles.findOne({_id: this.params._id});  // good to make these functions, so that they stay reactive
    }
  });  // you can set data context here too, which is accessible to all children

  this.render('Article', {});
}, {
  name: 'article.show'
});
```

Comment: Hi Goodword, You discovered a gotcha that I've run into myself too. Templates, including the layout, are rendered in a hierarchy. So when you set a data context further up in the hierarchy, it's visible to everything contained at that level. When you use contentFor, you're taking some DOM and moving it out from the template and into the layout. So, the data context should be set on the layout. If you use the "data" property, this happens automatically. Hope this helps!

Comment: @cmather.  It's an honor to have you commenting on my Stack overflow post.  got another iron-router related question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28256484/reactivity-in-iron-router-controller