# How do you render multiple templates with one route controller using iron-router?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, iron-router

- [URL to current version of my project](http://gwa-blog_from_scratch.meteor.com)
- [Here is the code for my project](https://github.com/goodwordalchemy/blog-from-scratch-with-meteor)

---

#### Background:

I am making a blog using meteor and iron-router.  I want to use a single controller for several different "category pages," which filter a list a blog articles in the yield region.

#### The Problem:

The article list does not get rerendered when the URL changes.  I.e. the article list is not reactive.  Interestingly, if I navigate back to the home page, the correct article list shows up.

#### The Question:

How do I make that article list change when I change between different routes on the category route controller?

---

#### Some example code:

Please note that the code for this whole project is available [here](https://github.com/goodwordalchemy/blog-from-scratch-with-meteor).

Here is my Route Controller:

```
CategoryController = RouteController.extend({
    action: function(){
        this.render();
    },
    template: 'category',
    data: function(){
        return {category: this.params.category};
    }
});

CategoryController.helpers({
    articles: function(){
        return Articles.find({category: this.params.category});
    }
});
```

And here is the template it is rendering:

```
<template name='category'>
    <div class="container">
        <h2>{{category}}:</h2>
        <ul>
            {{#each articles}}
                <li>
                {{#linkTo route="article.show"}}
                    {{title}}
                {{/linkTo}} 
                </li>
            {{/each}}
        </ul>
    </div>
</template>
```

---

#### Resources/Updates:

- Read [this article on Meteor Reactivity and the Deps Package](http://robertdickert.com/blog/2013/11/14/why-is-my-meteor-app-not-updating-reactively/).  Very interesting, but after trying some `Deps.autorun`s in different places, I don't think that this is the answer.
- Currently trying to make different "category" routes inherit from the controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The article list does not change because the Template helper is not using a reactive data source. You may use the `RouteController.getParams` method to establish a reactive dependency on route parameters as shown below.

```
CategoryController.helpers({
    articles: function(){
        var controller = this;
        var params = controller.getParams();

        return Articles.find({category: params.category});
    }
});
```

From [Iron Router documentation](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/blob/devel/Guide.md#route-parameters):

> Note: If you want to rerun a function when the hash changes you can do
>   this:
>
> ```
> // get a handle for the controller.
> // in a template helper this would be
> // var controller = Iron.controller();
> var controller = this;
>
> // reactive getParams method which will invalidate the comp if any part of the params change
> // including the hash.
> var params = controller.getParams();
> ```
>
> By default the router will follow normal browser behavior. If you
>   click a link with a hash frag it will scroll to an element with that
>   id. If you want to use controller.getParams() you can put that in
>   either your own autorun if you want to do something procedural, or in
>   a helper.